# C# Task async/await vs Golang's goroutines

Tags: c#, go, asynchronous, async-await, goroutine

I have been learning both C# and Golang for a while and trying to compare the ways they support asynchronous programming.

What I know about goroutines is that the go runtime can schedule the goroutines to run on different physical/machine threads. If a goroutine is blocked (e.g., synchronous waiting for I/O), the go runtime can suspend the goroutine and free the physical threads to run other goroutines.

C# `Task` is similar to goroutine in the sense that it is also an abstraction on top of physical threads. However, it is considered a bad idea to do blocking I/O inside an `async` `Task` because *"the entire thread will be blocked, causing deadlock"*. Can't the C# runtime do something similar to goroutines to suspend the blocked `async` `Task` and free the physical threads to run other `async` `Task`s?

I have been struggling for this problem for a while and couldn't find public materials explaining this better. Maybe my understanding is not correct. Can someone please help me?

Comment: "Can't the C# runtime do something similar to goroutines" Just because it's not totally impossible to do so doesn't mean C# actually _does_ this. It probably could at unknown cost as not designed to.

Comment: A C# task is an abstraction, but not on top of an OS thread. A C# thread is an abstraction on an OS thread. But tasks are only related to threads in the loosest possible sense. It doesn't matter that a "task blocks" on synchronous I/O; all your I/O should be async in a Task. Spend some time reading Stephen Cleary's blog. In particular, start with [There is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> C# Task is similar to goroutine in the sense that it is also an abstraction on top of physical threads.

At an extremely high view, yes, they can be similar.

> However, it is considered a bad idea to do blocking I/O inside an async Task because "the entire thread will be blocked, causing deadlock".

Blocking doesn't necessarily cause deadlocks, but blocking will block the calling thread until the task completes. That's the whole point.

> Can't the C# runtime do something similar to goroutines to suspend the blocked async Task and free the physical threads to run other async Tasks?

An async method can just use `await` to get the behavior you want. Blocking is specifically for blocking *threads*. Conceptually, goroutines are sort of like making every method `async` and implicitly using `await` everywhere.

In the more general case of the C# runtime doing something similar to goroutines for *any* blocking: the C# runtime cannot easily do this because of backwards compatibility. There's also a *lot* of legacy code that depends on "special threads" (UI threads, COM STA threads, etc) where a green threading / coroutine approach would be more difficult. Go has mostly avoided backwards incompatibility concerns by just creating an entirely new ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you Stephen for the answers despite the downvotes and my question being vague. This clarifies my doubts. Your blogs on async programming also enlighten me a lot in this area. Really appreciated it.